# javascript new regexp dynamic

Tags: javascript, php, regex, string

I am creating a dynamic `regex` but I have a problem with how to escape character so can one put some light on this?

I am using PHP with some backend configuration and admin can add `regexp` from backend to validate invalidate character and I am getting this value on the PHP so what I did

```
var regex = RegExp(<?php echo $regex ?>);
```

but I am getting the error like `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:` I know I need to escape the dynamic character but not sure how.

**EDIT**

I am trying this value from backend

```
<>{}[\]!@#$+=%^*()/;
```

**New EDIT**

As per the @anubhava suggested I am escaping the special character by `preg_quote()` but on Regex.test it always fails I mean it always getting the false even though It should return true.

Here is my code,

```
var invalidCharRe = new RegExp(SOME_MY_VARIABLE);
var result = invalidCharRe.test(value)
```

Where `SOME_MY_VARIABLE` is a dynamic special character(which I am getting from PHP by `preg_quote()` and `value` is my textbox value

Comment: Can you add the value that you're trying to use?

Comment: JavaScript regex should be enclosed with `/`, for example `var regex = RegExp(/<\?php echo \$regex \?>/);`. Please elaborate what exactly you want to achieve. I think the expression I wrote should match verbatim `<?php echo $regex ?>`.

Comment: Try this php instead: `<?php echo preg_quote($regex, '/'); ?>`

Comment: please see my edit @Archer

Comment: the question is for javascript because I am facing problem on `new RegExp` javascript function @anubhava

Comment: @KeyurShah You misunderstand the comment.  anubhava is correct.

Comment: @KeyurShah: Yes I understand that you want to create this regex in Javascript. However since string is coming from your php code, we can ask php to do escaping for us using `preg_quote`. Try below answer in your webapp and let me know it doesn't work for you for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `php` to echo your regex you can leverage php's [`preg_quote` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to escape all special regex meta-characters beforehand like this:

```
var regex = /<?php echo preg_quote($regex, '/'); ?>/
```

Note that there is no need to call `new RegExp` here since Javascript will be always be getting a static string for regex.

Comment: you added `/` at the beginning and end of a string for escape the character?

Comment: `/` before and after php tag is for Javascript syntax of regex creation e.g. `let re = /some_regex/`

Comment: could you please see my new edit @anubhava It is not working for me :(

Comment: But I am getting SOME_MY_VARIABLE through global javascript object that's why I wrote like this and If I write like this /SOME_MY_VARIABLE/ then it is considered as string

Comment: Thanks for the response, hence I can not add php code is purely .js file any suggestion for this?

Comment: Code that I suggested can be added in any `.js` file and it will emit a working javascript code once it is processed by PHP.

Comment: I mean purely js file means I have some `validation.js` file so I can not write php code inside this file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178867/discussion-between-anubhava-and-keyur-shah).

Comment: Here is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52041590/javascript-new-regex-dynamic-on-js-file